# MySQL Left outer join with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I am trying to use the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM top_lines t
LEFT OUTER JOIN last_24_topline AS l ON l.`member_no` = t.`member_no` 
    AND l.`mfg` = t.`line_no`
WHERE l.account_no = 32049 OR l.account_no IS NULL
```

However this is returning no rows, as there are no account_no rows in last_24_topline that match.  From all that I understand and have read this query should still return all the rows from top_lines, even though no rows match in last_24_topline since I am checking for a value or null, but it is not.  Are there any options or settings in MySQL (5.7.2) that would cause this behavior?
Just for information, this query works as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM top_lines t
LEFT OUTER JOIN last_24_topline l ON l.`member_no` = t.`member_no` 
    AND l.`mfg` = t.`line_no`
    AND l.`account_no` = 32049
```

I'm unable to use this construct however since I am using entity framework and you can only pass columns in and not values to the joins

---

```
CREATE TABLE `last_24_topline` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `branch_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_no` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_no` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salesperson_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mfg` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mfg_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_three` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `last_twelve` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ly_last_three` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ly_last_twelve` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_branch_no` (`branch_no`),
  KEY `ix_employee_no` (`employee_no`),
  KEY `ix_member_line_account` (`member_no`,`mfg`,`account_no`),
  KEY `ix_member_line` (`member_no`,`mfg`),
  KEY `ix_account_no` (`account_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `top_lines` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `line_no` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `line_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_line_no` (`member_no`,`line_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert  into `top_lines`(`id`,`member_no`,`line_no`,`line_description`) values (1,'520','772','FED ROTOR/DRUM');
insert  into `top_lines`(`id`,`member_no`,`line_no`,`line_description`) values (2,'520','952','FED SST CERAMIC');
insert  into `top_lines`(`id`,`member_no`,`line_no`,`line_description`) values (3,'520','954','FED SST FRICTION');
insert  into `top_lines`(`id`,`member_no`,`line_no`,`line_description`) values (4,'520','162','EVS FRICTION');

INSERT INTO `last_24_topline` (`id`, `member_no`, `branch_no`, `employee_no`, `account_no`, `salesperson_name`, `customer_name`, `mfg`, `mfg_description`, `last_three`, `last_twelve`, `ly_last_three`, `ly_last_twelve`) VALUES('1','520','0','10856','463854','FORD, JAMES,','JIFFY LUBE','459','FEDERATED AIR FILTER','0.00','15.21','0.00','0.00');
INSERT INTO `last_24_topline` (`id`, `member_no`, `branch_no`, `employee_no`, `account_no`, `salesperson_name`, `customer_name`, `mfg`, `mfg_description`, `last_three`, `last_twelve`, `ly_last_three`, `ly_last_twelve`) VALUES('2','520','0','10856','463854','FORD, JAMES,','JIFFY LUBE','460','FILTERS','0.00','0.00','0.00','16.48');
INSERT INTO `last_24_topline` (`id`, `member_no`, `branch_no`, `employee_no`, `account_no`, `salesperson_name`, `customer_name`, `mfg`, `mfg_description`, `last_three`, `last_twelve`, `ly_last_three`, `ly_last_twelve`) VALUES('3','520','0','10856','463854','FORD, JAMES,','JIFFY LUBE','863','SMP T SERIES','0.00','0.00','0.00','50.67');
```

---

I would expect, even with no data in last_24_topline that matches, for the first query to produce a result set containing all the rows in top_lines with null values for the columns from last_24_topline.

Expected results:
[image: expected results]

---

So, creating the same schema into another database and inserting only the example data I provided above, I get the results I expect.  I am testing further with copying the full rows to the second database to see if it still gives the expected results.

**update**
Copying all data into the new tables causes the problem to resurface.  I'm trying to pare down to the minimum necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, expected output for that sample data and the structure of the tables?

Comment: `l.account_no` will **only** be `NULL` if the row does not match the `ON` condition. So for any rows in `top_lines` that have a matching row in `last_24_topline` based on the `ON` condition, `l_account_no` will not be `NULL` and the second part of your `WHERE` clause won't select them.

Comment: @Nick that's why I'm using an OR in the where clause, so it can either have the matching account number, or be null

Comment: @D.Smania see updated question for table and sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the query without the account number in the join, the join *does* match row in the last_24_toplines table, but it *does not* match the account number in the where clause, so it is filtered out and not seen as a row from top_lines without a matching row from last_24_topline.

So, for example this row from the top_line table

[image]

Will match this row from the last_24_toplines

[image]

but both will then be filtered out, because the account_no didn't match what was in the where clause: **`WHERE l.account_no = 32049 OR l.account_no IS NULL`**

The query with the check for account_no within the join will still match the row from top_line, but *will not* have a matching row from last_24_topline, so you will get a row with top_lines data with null last_24_topline.

Answer (score 1):

Try detecting for empty string too, maybe the fields are not NULL, but empty strings.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    top_lines t
LEFT JOIN
    last_24_topline AS l ON l.member_no = t.member_no AND l.mfg = t.line_no
WHERE
    (l.account_no = '' OR l.account_no = '32049' OR l.account_no IS NULL)
```

If you want more help, i will need a sample data for "table last_24_topline" and the expected output after the join.

As a second try, you can use this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    top_lines t
LEFT JOIN
    last_24_topline AS l ON l.member_no = t.member_no AND l.mfg = t.line_no
WHERE
    l.id IS NULL
OR
    (l.id IS NOT NULL AND l.account_no = '32049')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a column involved in the join instead of `l.account_no` this way rows from top_lines will be returned if there is no matching row in the left table.

```
SELECT *
FROM top_lines t
LEFT OUTER JOIN last_24_topline AS l ON l.`member_no` = t.`member_no`
       AND l.`mfg` = t.`line_no`
WHERE l.account_no = 32049 OR l.`member_no` IS NULL
```

Alternatively place the account number filter directly in to the join

```
SELECT *
FROM top_lines t
LEFT OUTER JOIN last_24_topline AS l ON l.`member_no` = t.`member_no`
       AND l.`mfg` = t.`line_no`
       AND l.account_no = 32049
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, a good idea, but did not work.  I already know the second method works, but I can't use it with entity framework without a lot of rework which I'd rather solve by figuring out why the first method isn't working correctly.